# Creating a new matrix out of two sorted matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two `NxN` matrices `A` and `B`. I am looking to create a new `MxM` matrix `C` composed by the alternately placed matrices `A` and `B`.
The order in the even lines should be:  `A B A B A B`...
while the odd lines must start from the matrix `B`, as `B A B A`...

For example,

For `N=2`, if:

```
A = [1 2; 
     3 4];

B = [5 6; 
     7 8];
```

then for `M=2`

```
C = [A B; 
     B A];

%so that: 
C = [1 2 5 6; 
     3 4 7 8; 
     5 6 1 2; 
     7 8 3 4];
```

For `M=3`:

```
C = [A B A; 
     B A B; 
     A B A];
```

For `M=4`

```
C = [A B A B; 
     B A B A; 
     A B A B; 
     B A B A];
```

In this way, the resulting matrix will have all diagonal with the same matrix `A` or `B`.

How to do this?

Comment: Is the order mentioned in the text same as the one mentioned in the examples? Are there typos? If yes, please fix them

Comment: Please note that MATLAB has 1-based indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the matrix `[A B; B A]` and index into it modularly:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
B = [5 6; 7 8];
M = 3;
C = [A B; B A];
C = C(mod(0:size(A,1)*M-1, size(C,1))+1, mod(0:size(A,2)*M-1, size(C,2))+1);
```